# Show number of Page Views per Session based on Landing Page

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to know how number of pages user goes through depends on his landing page.

So for example:
[image: table of how number of page views depends on landing page]

I have tried going to: `Behavior -> Site Content -> All pages -> primary dimension: Landing Page`, but I don't know what I should select as a secondary dimension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go with "User Type" or "Page Depth" Levels in Secondary dimension.

While the same you could find as - Behavior -> Site Content -> Landing Page -> Page Depth